# Best way to show updated results

Tags: android, webview

Hey basicaly im developing an application for the rugby team i play for and need a way to display match results is there a way to update these easily within an application? or is it best to just use web view and link it to a html page i'd rather they didnt have to load a web page each time if at all possible but at the same time thats better than doing a full app update each week.

Thanks in advance
Ashley Waters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use xml parsing, in your app and check on each launch of your app if your live xml is updated, otherwise save the data and keep showing that data on your app.

Comment: thankyou ive just looked into it and read a couple of tutorials and this seems to be exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to create a web-service which throws/get request/response either in XML or JSON. While getting response you have to parse XML or JSON and display it inside the application.

If you want to update the application by making web call automatically then implement Background call and set timer for service so that it continuously check whether any data is updated at web or not.